# How can I convert a curved or sloping surface to a composition of only small orthogonal(vertical and horizontal) planes?

Tags: modeling, transforms, geometry-nodes, surface-deform

How can I convert a curved or sloping surface to a composition of only small orthogonal(vertical and horizontal) planes? like a composition of LEGO blocks

Comment: You may want to state your experience in time such as months with Blender.

Comment: If you want to voxellize the mesh (turn it to blocks in both directions, not just terraces along the slope) then check out the _Remesh_ modifier > _Blocks_

Answer (score 0):

A few alternative suggestions

---

- A sequence of boxes/scaled cubes can be created with the array modifier and the modifier can be [applied].  Vertex groups can be created for the top surface.  Then shrinkwrap modifier can be used on that vertex group.  That is the top of the boxes can conform to your existing surface.
- See the remesh modifier.  It has many options.
- You may also consider geometry nodes, geo nodes, GN.  There many recent questions and videos on this topic. GN is quite a la mode.  GN requires more time to learn.  There are probably examples of this exact topic, or nearest projection, on the famous video website that has a name that rhymes with noonoob.  Suggestion ... search geometry nodes, first at the other website, then here BSE.  I am using Blender for a time consuming operation. Thus at the moment I am not providing an image.